# Как сформировать правильный запрос PG?

Tags: postgresql

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM post
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = json_array_elements(post.items)->0
WHERE post.name = 'furious'
```

Но возникает ошибка: set-returning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions

Задача:

1. Взять из таблицы post колонку items, которая заполнена двумерным массивом [[1, 'fgdgf'], [3, 'dfgdfg']]
2. Получить айди, то есть 1 и 3
3. Отправить запрос на получение всех данных из таблицы items по полученным данным (1 и 3)

Как правильно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты неправильно используешь  `json_array_elements`. Эта функция возвращает резалтсет, а не массив.

Вот так у меня работает

```
CREATE TABLE POST ( ITEMS JSON);
INSERT INTO POST VALUES( '[[1, "fgdgf"], [3, "dfgdfg"]]');

SELECT *
FROM
    POST
    CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(POST.ITEMS) POST_ITEMS (SUBARRAY)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 ID
        UNION SELECT 2 ID
    ) ITEMS ON ITEMS.ID = (SUBARRAY ->> 0)::INT
```

Но что интересно, не смог заставить работать `ITEMS.ID = (SUBARRAY -> 0)`, пришлось через текстовое преобразование прогнать.